# Importing JPG into SWMM model asks for BPW world file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, world-file

I need to import a jpg image of a map into EPA SWMM model but it asks for the world coordinates file (*.bpw) of this image. How can I get this file?

How can I open a georeferenced-JPG file in the EPA-SWMM as a backdrop image with its world coordinates file?

Comment: Can you confirm it is actually asking for a `BPW` file specifically?

Comment: Convert jpg to bmp and rename world file

Comment: View > Backdrop > Backdrop Image Selector